# In this passage from "Swimming in the Dark", does "came through to the corridor with me" mean they came out through the room to the corridor?

Tags: meaning, swimming-in-the-dark, tomasz-jedrowski

I would like to know what "came through to the corridor with me" means in the following sentences:

> ‘No, thank you,’ you said, waiting for her to stop. ‘I won’t trouble
> you for long. Ludwik told me you haven’t been well. I managed to get
> you a doctor’s appointment. Tomorrow at ten.’ You handed her a card.
>
> She looked at it, squinting, reaching for her glasses. ‘But *Pan*
> Janusz, this is a *private* doctor,’ she muttered, looking concerned. ‘I
> don’t think I can—’
>
> ‘He won’t accept payment,’ you said. ‘Don’t worry.’
>
> She considered you for a moment, very seriously. ‘*Pan* Janusz, how can
> I accept this?’
>
> ‘It’s nothing. A favour being returned, that’s all.’ You glanced at me
> for a moment.
>
> *Pani* Kolecka’s face broke into an involuntary smile. ‘I don’t know how
> to thank you. Please, stay for lunch.’
>
> ‘Thank you, but I have to go, and you need to rest. Another time. When
> you feel better.’ You got up and shook her hand, and **came through to
> the corridor with me**.
>
> I wanted to thank you but I couldn’t.

- [Tomasz Jedrowski, *Swimming in the Dark*, Chapter 5](https://www.booker6.com/book/202006/842_42.html)

In this novel, which is set in the 1980's in Poland under the socialist regime, where homosexuality was socially unacceptable, the protagonist Ludwik (a university graduate) left Poland in 1981 to live in the United States of America. And he remembers what it was like back then in Poland, where he was frustrated by the reality of this socialist regime that he couldn't even get a doctor's appointment when his dear landlady was sick. (She was like a grandmother to him). But days later, his lover Janusz came to give her the ticket for a doctor's appointment.

In this part, I wonder what "come through to" means. Would that mean that they came out through the room to the corridor...?

I am an English learner from South Korea, so thank you for your patience in advance as I may not know obvious things. I would very much appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of this passage, Janusz leaves the room and walks into the corridor. The preposition "through" is used here because Janusz walks through the [doorway](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doorway) that separates the room from the corridor.